# Custom data push message with Firebase with platform-specific notification issue

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have some issues with sending custom push message using `Firebase Cloud Messaging` with my data.

On iOS I have created Notification Service Provider that controlls every incoming notification but I had to add `"notification"` field with `title` and `body` in push request to Firebase. If there was no `"notification"` field then if app was turned off/killed then I couldn't receive message.

On Android I have my `FirebaseMessagingService` where I receive messages (and I can decide what to do with it) but if `"notification"` field is present in Firebase request then `FirebaseMessagingService` is not receiving message but notification shows automatically with `title` and `body` from "notification".

I've found some docs from `Firebase` about platform-specific messages
([When to use platform-specific keys](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#when_to_use_platform-specific_keys)) and I though to add notification only for iOS platform. I have tried few approches described in link above and here [Creating the Remote Notification Payload](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CreatingtheNotificationPayload.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH10-SW1) / [Payload Key Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/PayloadKeyReference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH17-SW1)

Below some examples of JSON I've tried to send but I always get error `InvalidParameters: Invalid notification payload` (I've tried all possibilities with fields `apns`, `payload`, `aps`, `alert`)

```
{
    "to": "xyz................", //single device with android or ios
    "mutable_content": true,
    "data": { "field1": "value1" [.......] },
    "apns": {
    "payload": {
        "title": "Some message title",
        "body": "Some message body",
        "sound": "default"    
    }
}
```

or

```
{
    "to": "xyz................", //single device with android or ios
    "mutable_content": true,
    "data": { "field1": "value1" [.......] },
    "apns": {
    "payload": {
        "aps": {
            "title": "Some message title",
            "body": "Some message body",
            "sound": "default"   
        }  
    }
}
```

etc.

The purpose is to receive `data` in my app and decide how to handle it - depending on incoming data I want to show my own notification or make some custom action in app.

Is it even possible to send platform-specific message to iOS with notification/alert and without it to Android? If so - how?

Comment: Platform Overrides are only available for FCM v1. Can you show an actual sample request and how you're sending them. It's hard to tell anything from what the post is right now.

Comment: @AL. For testing purposes I'm sending push message using ```Postman``` and ```Firebase``` API ```https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send``` with key in header and json as in my post above

Comment: AFAIK, requests made for FCM v1 *require* an [Access Token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#credentials) in order for it to work.

Comment: @AL. Okay, so I'm using old legacy protocol and this is the reason why platform-specific messages are not working... I have to migrate to FCM v1 and it should work. Thank you for your help

Comment: Possibly. I'm not 100% sure. Good luck with your app.

Comment: @AL. it worked! thank you!